# How to limit NSTextView to only 1 line?

Tags: objective-c, nstextview

I have instantiated the NSTextView in the code.
I would like to set the line limit to 1 line in a property.
I would rather not have to use a delegate.

Comment: `NSTextField` is one line.

Comment: it's NSTextView not field

Comment: Why don't you use a `NSTextField` instead of a `NSTextView`?

Answer (score 2):

You could just use an `NSTextField` instead of an `NSTextView`, they are easier to use as well

Comment: I don't like the graphic portion:  border, inability to have a different background color compared to another NSTextField

Comment: well its sounds like your only option is to implement a delegate because I don't think you can simply disable multiple lines in a text view

Comment: @jdl You can set the background color and the border in the inspector!? I don't get your point. However, on editing you always get an instance of `NSTextView` as field editor, which is shared between the text fields and views. Please read the documentation of `-fieldEditor:forObject:`.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to solve this, so I created a single line NSTextField and then examined all the settings of its NSTextView field editor and the associated NSTextContainer.

By using similar settings, I created an NSTextView that is limited to one line and behaves exactly like NSTextField for left, center and right aligned text.

```
NSRect superViewFrame = NSMakeRect(...) // set coordinates of frame in superview coordinates

// create the scroll view
NSRect scrollFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, superviewFrame.width, superViewFrame.height);
NSScrollView* scrollview = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: scrollFrame];

[scrollview setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
[scrollview setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
[scrollview setHasVerticalScroller:NO];

// create the NSTextView
NSTextView* view = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:superviewFrame];

[view setMinSize:superviewFrame.size]; // this is critical; it cannot be (0,0)!
[view setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(1000000, 1000000)]; // NSTextField field editor Values = 40000, 40000
[view setAlignment:align];
[view setHorizontallyResizable:YES];
[view setVerticallyResizable:YES];
[[view textContainer] setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(1000000, 20000000)]; // NSTextField field editor Values = 40000, 10000000
[[view textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:NO];
[[view textContainer] setHeightTracksTextView:NO];

// install view in scroll view
[scrollview setDocumentView:view];
```

Once this is complete, install the scroll view into its superview.

Tested on Mojave (10.14.6) and Monterey (12.6.5)